# Issue with Combining LSTM and CNN? (Python, Keras)

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I want to predict 8-characters license plates, so I wrote the below model in Keras:

```
x = Input(shape=(HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS))
base_model = InceptionV3(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS))
base_model.trainable = False
y = base_model(x)
y = Reshape((8, 9 * 256))(y)
y = LSTM(units=20, return_sequences='true')(y)
y = Dropout(0.5)(y)
y = TimeDistributed(Dense(TOTAL_CHARS, activation="softmax", activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(REGUL_PARAM)))(y)
y = Dropout(0.25)(y)
model = Model(input=x, output=y)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I have about 6000 data for training which I augment them with ImageGenerator. My problem is that the loss and accuracy are approximately constant during time:

```
************************************************************
Epoch: 1
************************************************************
Train on 6869 samples, validate on 1718 samples
Epoch 1/1
6856/6869 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5.4525 - acc: 0.1924Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from 2.17175 to 2.15020, saving model to ./trained_model_V10.hdf5
6869/6869 [==============================] - 25s 4ms/step - loss: 5.4535 - acc: 0.1924 - val_loss: 2.1502 - val_acc: 0.2232
************************************************************
Epoch: 2
************************************************************
Train on 6869 samples, validate on 1718 samples
Epoch 1/1
6848/6869 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5.4543 - acc: 0.1959Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from 2.15020 to 2.11809, saving model to ./trained_model_V10.hdf5
6869/6869 [==============================] - 26s 4ms/step - loss: 5.4537 - acc: 0.1958 - val_loss: 2.1181 - val_acc: 0.2281
************************************************************
Epoch: 3
************************************************************
Train on 6869 samples, validate on 1718 samples
Epoch 1/1
6856/6869 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5.4284 - acc: 0.1977Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from 2.11809 to 2.09679, saving model to ./trained_model_V10.hdf5
6869/6869 [==============================] - 25s 4ms/step - loss: 5.4282 - acc: 0.1978 - val_loss: 2.0968 - val_acc: 0.2304
************************************************************
Epoch: 4
************************************************************
Train on 6869 samples, validate on 1718 samples
Epoch 1/1
6856/6869 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5.4500 - acc: 0.2004Epoch 00001: val_loss did not improve
6869/6869 [==============================] - 25s 4ms/step - loss: 5.4490 - acc: 0.2004 - val_loss: 2.1146 - val_acc: 0.2355
************************************************************
Epoch: 5
************************************************************
Train on 6869 samples, validate on 1718 samples
Epoch 1/1
6848/6869 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5.4399 - acc: 0.2006Epoch 00001: val_loss did not improve
6869/6869 [==============================] - 25s 4ms/step - loss: 5.4374 - acc: 0.2009 - val_loss: 2.1102 - val_acc: 0.2324
************************************************************
Epoch: 6
************************************************************
Train on 6869 samples, validate on 1718 samples
Epoch 1/1
6856/6869 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5.4636 - acc: 0.1977Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from 2.09679 to 2.09076, saving model to ./trained_model_V10.hdf5
6869/6869 [==============================] - 25s 4ms/step - loss: 5.4629 - acc: 0.1978 - val_loss: 2.0908 - val_acc: 0.2341
************************************************************
```

Now, I am not sure exactly the correctness of my model and I think the problem is my model. Is this the correct way to combine CNN and LSTM?

I also have tried the below mode:

```
REGUL_PARAM = 0
image = Input(shape=(HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS))
x = Reshape((8, HEIGHT, int(WIDTH/8), CHANNELS))(image)
y = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(REGUL_PARAM)))(x)
y = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))(y)
y = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(REGUL_PARAM)))(y)
y = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))(y)
y = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(REGUL_PARAM)))(y)
y = Reshape((int(y.shape[1]), int(y.shape[4]*y.shape[3]*y.shape[2])))(y)
y = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences='true'))(y)
y = TimeDistributed(Dense(64, activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(REGUL_PARAM), activation='relu'))(y)
y = Dropout(0.25)(y)
y = TimeDistributed(Dense(TOTAL_CHARS, activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(REGUL_PARAM), activation='softmax'))(y)
y = Dropout(0.25)(y)

model = Model(inputs=image, outputs=y)
```

the accuracy for this is about 70%, but the point is that I cannot overfit even on a small potion of my data.

Comment: So, you're giving the LSTMs 8 time steps, right??? But, are your images divided in 8 characters?? If your images are entire license plates, this model will never work. How is it supposed to fit exactly each character in each time step? (Especially if you're doing augmentation or if your photos are not taken all exactly from the same angle matching the 8 steps exactly).

Comment: Yes each license plate consists of 8 characters. I used LSTM for the network to use the information of previous prediction for new prediction, for example if it splits a character wrong it can used previous character information to predict this one. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, your model doesn't work well.

You may take a look at this [code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_cnn_lstm.py).

```
'''Train a recurrent convolutional network on the IMDB sentiment
classification task.
Gets to 0.8498 test accuracy after 2 epochs. 41s/epoch on K520 GPU.
'''
from __future__ import print_function

from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D
from keras.datasets import imdb

# Embedding
max_features = 20000
maxlen = 100
embedding_size = 128

# Convolution
kernel_size = 5
filters = 64
pool_size = 4

# LSTM
lstm_output_size = 70

# Training
batch_size = 30
epochs = 2

'''
Note:
batch_size is highly sensitive.
Only 2 epochs are needed as the dataset is very small.
'''

print('Loading data...')
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)
print(len(x_train), 'train sequences')
print(len(x_test), 'test sequences')

print('Pad sequences (samples x time)')
x_train = sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=maxlen)
x_test = sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=maxlen)
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print('x_test shape:', x_test.shape)

print('Build model...')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, embedding_size, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv1D(filters,
                 kernel_size,
                 padding='valid',
                 activation='relu',
                 strides=1))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size))
model.add(LSTM(lstm_output_size))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Train...')
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score, acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size)
print('Test score:', score)
print('Test accuracy:', acc)
```

Comment: Thanks zhong, but still I cannot find out my problem.